# File system, unexpected write/read on disk output

Tags: c, embedded, keil

I've been working on this for 3 days, can't see the error, I need fresh eyes :)
I work on a online embedded class, and at this particular lab we need to implement a file system.
I have unexpected results as described in the code comments in the main function. (E=expected, R=result)

**Write/read functions:**

```
#define EDISK_ADDR_MIN      0x00020000  // Flash Bank1 minimum address
#define EDISK_ADDR_MAX      0x0003FFFF  // Flash Bank1 maximum address
// Write an array of 32-bit data to flash starting at given address.
 int Flash_FastWrite(uint32_t *source, uint32_t addr, uint16_t count)
{
 uint32_t flashkey;
 uint32_t volatile *FLASH_FWBn_R = (uint32_t volatile*)0x400FD100;
 int writes = 0;
  if(MassWriteAddrValid(addr))
 {
  DisableInterrupts();  // may be optional step
  while(FLASH_FMC2_R&FLASH_FMC2_WRBUF){}; // wait for hardware idle
   while((writes < 32) && (writes < count))
  {
   FLASH_FWBn_R[writes] = source[writes];
   writes = writes + 1;
  }
  FLASH_FMA_R = addr;
  if(FLASH_BOOTCFG_R&FLASH_BOOTCFG_KEY)  // by default, the key is 0xA442
   flashkey = FLASH_FMC_WRKEY;
  else                                  // otherwise, the key is 0x71D5
   flashkey = FLASH_FMC_WRKEY2;
  FLASH_FMC2_R = (flashkey|FLASH_FMC2_WRBUF);    // start writing
  while(FLASH_FMC2_R&FLASH_FMC2_WRBUF){};
  EnableInterrupts();
 }
  return writes;
}

// Write 1 sector of 512 bytes of data to the disk, data comes from RAM
enum DRESULT eDisk_WriteSector(
const uint8_t *buff,  // Pointer to the data to be written
uint8_t sector){     // sector number
uint32_t addr;
uint32_t *copybuff;
copybuff =(uint32_t*)(buff);//Flash_WriteArray needs uint32_t format
addr=EDISK_ADDR_MIN+(512*sector);// starting ROM address 
if(addr>EDISK_ADDR_MAX) // return RES_PARERR if exceeds 
    return RES_PARERR;
Flash_WriteArray(copybuff, addr, 512);// write 512 bytes from RAM into ROM                                       
                                      // written by the instructor.
return RES_OK;
}

// Read 1 sector of 512 bytes from the disk, data goes to RAM
enum DRESULT eDisk_ReadSector(
uint8_t *buff,     // Pointer to a RAM buffer into which to store
uint8_t sector){        // sector number to read from
        uint16_t i;
        uint8_t *diskpt;
diskpt=(uint8_t *)(EDISK_ADDR_MIN+512*sector);      // starting ROM address 
if(EDISK_ADDR_MIN+512*sector>EDISK_ADDR_MAX)    
    return RES_PARERR;
else
 {
    for ( i = 0; i < 512; i++ )// copy 512 bytes from ROM into RAM
        buff[i] = *diskpt++;
    return RES_OK;
 }
}
enum DRESULT eDisk_Format(void){
// erase all flash from EDISK_ADDR_MIN to EDISK_ADDR_MAX
for(uint32_t i=EDISK_ADDR_MIN;i<=EDISK_ADDR_MAX;i++)
    Flash_Erase(i);
return RES_OK;
}

uint8_t Buff[512];
 int main(void)
{
 eDisk_Init(0); // if(drive == 0){return RES_OK;}             
 eDisk_Format();
 testbuildbuff("auf0");
 eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,0); 
 testbuildbuff("Excelent"); // writes "Excelent" onto Buff
 eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,1); 
 testbuildbuff("bus3");
 eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,2);
 testbuildbuff("bus4");
 eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,3);
 // E=expected. R=result
 eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 0); //E: Buff="auf0" R:Buff="auf0"
 eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 1); //E: Buff="Excelent" R: Buff is empty
 eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 2); //E: Buff="bus3" R: Buff is empty
 eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 3); //E: Buff="bus4" R: 4Buff is empty
 return 0;
}
```

The `Buff` results after reed are unexpected. Why does it work for 0 but not the rest?

Even more strange is when I run this test:

```
testbuildbuff("auf0 buf1 buf2");
eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,2); 
testbuildbuff("Excelent");
eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,1); 
testbuildbuff("bus3");
eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,3);
testbuildbuff("bus4");
eDisk_WriteSector(Buff,4);
eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 4); //Buff is empty
eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 3); //Buff is empty
eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 2); //Buff = "auf0 buf1 buf2"
eDisk_ReadSector(Buff, 1); //Buff = "Excelent"
```

What is happening?

PS: IDE Keil uVision v5.2, uC: TM4C123

Comment: Incomplete code, bad formatting and the unclear description are making this question unanswerable.

Comment: what code is missing? Flash_WriteArray function was written by the course instructor, thus is good.                                                             
    //------------Flash_WriteArray------------
    // Write an array of 32-bit data to flash starting at given address.
    // Input: source pointer to array of 32-bit data
    //        addr   4-byte aligned flash memory address to start writing
    //        count  number of 32-bit writes
    // Output: number of successful writes; return value == count if 
    completely successful

Comment: testbuildbuff(), eDisk_Init(), and eDisk_Format() are all missing.  If the count parameter of `Flash_WriteArray()` represents the number of 32-bit writes then the value of 512 bytes that you are passing is incorrect.

Comment: @kkrambo THANK YOU! That is it, should be 128. I knew I needed fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: How do I close the question?

Comment: You don't close the question - that is not how SO works - though it is attracting close votes and may get closed in any case unless you choose to "save" it from oblivion, .  It does not have an answer yet (only comments).  @kkrambo might post an answer or you can answer it yourself - or someone may steal his answer, or post a better one.  Either way all SO questions are persistent and remain as a community resource.  In the meantime you should further improve the question to prevent it getting further down-votes - I have applied all the typographical fixes for you.

Comment: I would suggest refraining from describing things as "bizarre" and rather clearly describe what you expected, what actually happened, and how they differ.  I appreciate that you have included that information in the code comments, but it is probably best to at least mention that fact in the body text.  For example include _"... unexpected results as described in the code comments in the test `main()`."_

Comment: I like "Excelent".  That says it all.

Comment: Seems a bit asymmetrical and counter intuitive to have the write API use `uint32_t`, while the read uses `uint8_t`.  Such API inconsistency leads to errors - as you have discovered.  If the flash only supports 32 bit writes (or is faster that way), then by all means use 32 bit writes, but that is an implementation technology detail and should not be exposed at the API level.  Hide that by using a cast to `uint32_t*` internally to the write,

Answer (score 3):

The issue is at call of function Flash_WriteArray().
In Flash_WriteArray(), the last parameter should be the number of words (32-bit or 4 bytes) we want to write. To write 512 bytes, this parameter should be 128 (512/4).

Answer (score -1):

Writing words and reading bytes may give you an endian issue if your cpu is big endian.